# Lookup Column Issue - List View Threshold exceeded

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We use Sharepoint Foundation 2010 and we have 2 Lists in a site. Those are:

1. Customers List.
2. Sale Invoices List.

Customers List has Title field as Unique & Indexed Column.

Sale Invoices List has a lookup column (i.e., Customer) from the Customers List (Title).

My issue is:

Customers List has just crossed 5000 items. When I try to add a List Item in Sale Invoices List (where I have Lookup Column from Customers List), it throws an error as given below:

Error Message:- **This is a lookup column that displays data from another list that currently exceeds the List View Threshold defined by the administrator (5000). To add items to the current list, please ask the list owner to remove this column.**

I have increased **temporarily** the List View Threshold Limit to 6000 Items. It’s working fine now.

Is there any solution to fix the issue without increasing the List Items Threshold Limit?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into archiving list items. Another thing you can  think about doing is creating different lists for different time periods so that you can avoid this List View Threshold and your list queries can be as fast as possible.

Check this out: http://referpages.com/wp/2012/04/101/